# Runaway argument after Table error

Tags: sectioning, write-file

I'm somewhat of a Tex beginner, but I've been running into this problem a lot lately, so I'm really hoping for some help.

I have a large table in the appendix of my file, and it caused me quite a bit of a headache before (getting "runaway argument" errors and such). However, I did get it to compile correctly a while back. Since then, I have not worked on the table, only on text.

Now, I'm getting the following error message when I try to compile:

```
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {chapter}{\num 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.70 \begin{document}
```

I have absolutely no idea where to look for my mistake, has anyone encountered this before?

I've tried deleting all the temporary files, I've tried letting it finish the compilation through the "q" command, and so far, nothing has helped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a short example that generates the error?  You might find it helpful to look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: You have probably got an unbalanced } somewhere...

Comment: @Thruston
nope, already checked the } s.
I have each chapter in a different file (then \input them into the main file). So I've eliminated all chapters, deleted all temporary data, then put them back in one by one. It's the one that consists of nothing but the table that is causing the trouble.
Which compiled just 15 fine 15 minutes ago.
I'll check your link then get back with more information...

Comment: You have mis-matched `{}` in your `aux` file so you need to delete your aux file. The cause is probably using a fragile command in a chapter heading and forgetting to use `\protect`.

Comment: @David Carlisle:
As I mentioned, I've already deleted all temporary files, to no avail.

Comment: @Thruston:
So, I checked, and rechecked, and the problem is this: I included \usepackage{graphicx} and \usepackage{pdflscape} as well as \usepackage{longtable}.

Using \begin{landscape} \begin{longtable}, then put in the table, then end both is making the compilation crash. Any alternatives here?

Comment: It's impossible to make sensible suggestions without being able to see the table!  Now that you have narrowed down the problem, can you post a MWE?

Comment: No, TeX is _telling_ you you have mis-matched braces in the aux file, you should believe it:-)

Answer (score 1):

The full error message of the question shows several clues:

```
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {chapter}{\num 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.70 \begin{document}
```

`\@writefile` is usually called in the `.aux` file to move an entry for the table of contents from the `.aux` file to the `.toc` file. According to `\contentsline{chapter}`, the entry is an entry for a chapter. The abrupt stopping at `\num` – expected is `\numberline` – and the message `File ended` indicate, that the `.aux` file is truncated.

The reasons are usually a full file system or a crash of the previous LaTeX run.

In the latter case, more pieces of information are needed:

- TeX compiler: TeX, pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX
  Check the first line of the `.log` file.
- Mode of pdfTeX/LuaTeX: PDF or DVI
- Try to identify the place in the source code, where TeX crashes.
  For example, `\typeout{...}` can be used to put markers, which are printed on the screen/`.log` file. Because of the crash, buffers might not be written, thus the `.log` file or other auxiliary files can be too short.
  Since the crash already occurs in the first run, the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`, ...) should be deleted to avoid follow-up errors because of truncated auxiliary files.

Comment: LuaTeX, Version beta-0.79.1 (TeX Live 2014/Arch Linux) (rev 4971)

And I have no idea how to put markers anywhere. I delete the auxiliary files after each run anyways. And by now, I'd be happy to use any other package for the landscape-format, if someone knows one...

Comment: @NeedHelp Of course you can spend your time with replacing each package. Identifying the cause of the problem is much more useful: LuaTeX is work in progress and not as stable as pdfTeX. A proper bug report would help to get LuaTeX more stable, when the cause is fixed. Also it would be known, which feature is affected and whether replacing any package would make any sense.

Comment: @NeedHelp Usually `.aux` files cannot be deleted after *each* single run, because they are needed for the later runs: table of contents, references, ...

Comment: @NeedHelp Putting a "marker" is quite easy, just write `\typeout{This is a marker}` somewhere in the source file and check, whether you can see `This is a marker` in the console output. Also try to strip down the document without loosing its ability to crash to get a minimal example, which you can then post here for others to analyze and help.